# Getting xkcd plots using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

The current version of matplotlib (1.3.1) supports xkcd-style plotting, but when I [follow the basic instructions](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/07/10/XKCD-plots-in-matplotlib/) for generating such a plot (in iPython 1.1.0),

```
%pylab
plt.xkcd()
plt.plot(sin(linspace(0, 10)))
plt.title('Whoo Hoo!!!')
```

I get

[image]

instead of

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant? "Also, if you want to have the font match above, be sure to download and install the Humor Sans font on your system. For matplotlib to recognize it, you may have to remove the font cache, found on your system"

Comment: @jabey: Doh! How did I miss that? Is there a current recommended version to get (the link is dead). Also, the missing font alone can't explain the lines, which don't seem to be xkcdified.

Comment: What backend are you using for matplotlib? You can check with `plt.get_backend()`. Try setting it to a *Agg backend, such as Qt4Agg if you have Qt4 installed. You can also use the 'inline' backend with pylab if you're in an ipython notebook. e: see this issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2269

Comment: the `plt.xkcd` command takes a number of parameters to tune the amount of manipulation it performs. see it's docstring for more info.

Comment: @aganders3: MacOSX. I can't switch to qt because that leads me into all kinds of bugs trying to install sip.

Comment: @PaulH: Supplying those arguments doesn't have any effect for me.

Comment: I don't think the `plt.xkcd` works with the OSX backend. Try writing your plot to a file with the AGG backend, instead of using an interactive backend. If you need this interactively you will need GTK or Qt or Tk.

Comment: @aganders3: If that's the case, then that's probably the answer to my question.

Comment: I have a similar problem, only that I get the lines and not the font. How do you download the font? Txs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get it working, you need

- matplotlib 1.3.1 (it won't work with matplotlib 1.3.0 or earlier)

  - `sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade`
- font  *Humor Sans*

  - download from [here](http://antiyawn.com/uploads/humorsans.html) or [here](https://github.com/shreyankg/xkcd-desktop/blob/master/Humor-Sans.ttf), install (on OS X you open it and click Install)
- remove the matplotlib font cache (as suggested by [DanHickstein in matplotlib/issues/2269](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2269))

  - `rm ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache`

Now, execute the code and it should work.

You **do not need** to change backend to `TkAgg`, as some people suggest. For me it works perfectly fine on `'module://IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.backend_inline'` (you can check it by `plt.get_backend()`).

(I had the same problem and I've solved it, at least on OS X 10.8.5, with matplotlib 1.3.1 and IPython 2.0.0; removing font cache was necessary to get the font running.)

Comment: For matplotlib 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, the cache is in `~/.cache/matplotlib` (not sure when that changed) and deleting it is indeed vital.

Comment: Same is true for matplotlib 1.4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: maybe also /tmp/xdgcache/matplotlib directory in 1.4.2 version

Comment: matplotlib font cache on Win7: `%userprofile%\.matplotlib\fontList.cache` - [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26106170/5276734)

Comment: I also had to delete `fontList.py3k.cache`.

Comment: As suggested below, the font cache can be cleared directly from within Python via `import matplotlib` and then `matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()`. This should be platform-independent.

Answer (score 4):

Using ubuntu 16.04 and  python 3, with matplotlib 2.0.0 installed the following fixes the problem for me.

1. Install Comic sans: `sudo apt install fonts-humor-sans`
2. Remove matplotlib cache: `rm ~/.cache/matplotlib -r`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `fonts-humor-sans` installed.

In Ubuntu/Debian, you can install them with (from the command-line):

> $ sudo apt install python3-xkcd fonts-humor-sans

Then the best option (instead of deleting the matplotlib cache) is to rebuild the font manager (from within the Python interpreter, script or Jupyter notebook):

> import matplotlib
> matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()

Answer (score 0):

From the [blog post you linked](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/07/10/XKCD-plots-in-matplotlib/):

> Also, if you want to have the font match above, be sure to download and install the Humor Sans font on your system. For matplotlib to recognize it, you may have to remove the font cache...

As far as which version of the font to download, I would try the most current.

Comment: See edited comment above: I've got the font now, but the lines are still not xkcdified.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius are you using the right version of matplotlib?

Comment: I think so: added version number to question.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius no idea then, never written anything in python before, just thought it might be the missing font :P

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: The matplptlib font cache has to be cleared after the font is installed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085867/matplotlib-font-not-found/26106170#26106170