# matplotlib font not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to use the font "Heuristica" in my matplotlib plots, but it won't show up.

I defined "Heuristica" on the first spot in the rcParameter font.serif --> no result

I changed font.family to "Heuristica" and got the message

```
findfont: FontFamily not found
```

that got me thinking, because Heuristica is installed and I can access it from other software without problems. So I used the fontManager and did:

```
import pylab as pl
la = pl.matplotlib.font_manager.FontManager()
lu = pl.matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(family = 'Heuristica')
la.findfont(lu)
```

and got:

```
Out[7]: 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Heuristica-Regular.otf'
```

So obviously Heuristica can be found.
I looked up the available ttf-Fonts ([How can i get list of font family(or Name of Font) in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821795/how-can-i-get-list-of-font-familyor-name-of-font-in-matplotlib/18821968#18821968)) but Heuristica is not in this list.

I'd be glad about any help.

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 1.3.1

Comment: try updating to 1.4.0.  If that does not work please make an issue on github

Comment: The problem persist under 1.4.0. Are you sure that is really an issue for Github and not an issue with the person in front of my PC? Regarding a github issue: May I link to this question or do I a copy & paste?

Comment: Please put enough information is the issue that we don't have to link back to SO.  Questions here are not stable (both due to edits and deletions).  Please include enough detail that someone with a windows machine can reproduce it (including if you have changed your rcparam file and the _full_ traceback).

Comment: We now have an Issue on Github:  [#3590](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3590)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well, mdboom solved the problem over at [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3590), all the credit belongs to him:

> When you add new fonts to your system, you need to delete your fontList.cache file in order for matplotlib to find them.
>
> The reason it works on lines 4/5 in your example is because you are creating a FontManager from scratch (which goes out to the filesystem and hunts down all the fonts). Internally, when matplotlib later does its own font lookup, it is using a FontManager that has been loaded from a cache on disk in the fontList.cache file.
>
> Long term, we have plans to switch to using the font lookup mechanisms of the OS to get around this problem, (see MEP14), but in the meantime, you'll need to remove the fontList.cache file everytime you want matplotlib to discover new fonts.

The file fontList.cache is located at your Userfolder --> .matplotlib/fontList.cache, for Windows that would normally be `C:\Users\yourUsername\.matplotlib\fontList.cache`

Comment: `~/.cache/matplotlib` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nevertheless, it does not work, the font manager is unable to find any reasonable font.

Comment: I tried the solution only on windows and can't test on Linux. But maybe you want to add something to the github Issue, which is probably the best way to get a bugfix: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3590

Comment: This came as a suggested edit and I think it is worth mentioning (though I did not check if it is true): If you are using the WinPython distribution you need to also delete the font cache found in e.g.: C:\Python3\settings\.matplotlib It is not sufficient to delete the font cache in your home folder, Matplotlib will still be using the second font cache.

Comment: This hasnt worked for me. Matplotlib version 1.5.1. Is there a new way around this perhaps?

Comment: @ashley On Windows you need to look in %HOMEPATH%\.matplotlib. There's a file fontList.py3k.cache. Delete it. If you are using jupyter notebooks you must restart jupyter before the new fonts are picked up and the cache recreated.

Comment: I also had to delete `fontList.json`.

Comment: Forcing matplotlib to rebuild the cache is probably the most cross-platform solution with `import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager; font_manager._rebuild()`

Comment: For me the file was called `fontlist-v330.json`

Answer (score 3):

For some versions of Matplotlib, it may be necessary to clear the LRU cache of `_get_fontconfig_fonts()` (next to removing the `fontList.cache` file).

```py
fm = matplotlib.font_manager
fm._get_fontconfig_fonts.cache_clear()
```

This function is responsible for calling, and caching, `fc-list` on a Linux/Unix system. If your font appears in `fc-list`, and not in Matplotlib's fonts, even after removing the `fontList.cache` file, this may be the culprit.