# How to show different language in matplotlib barchart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to show a **Barchart** which will show the frequency of each character in Bangla Language in a particular text. But it shows empty box in horizontal positions.

```py
def GTStat():
    charFreq = {'ক': 30041, 'খ': 22981, 'র': 20806, 'ট': 19265, 'প': 16943, 'ন': 15478, 'ত': 13840}
    plt.bar(range(len(charFreq)), list(charFreq.values()), align='center')
    plt.xticks(range(len(charFreq)), list(charFreq.keys()))
    plt.show()
```

But it shows empty box instead of characters
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a font that supports your language like this:

```py
def GTStat():
    charFreq = {'ক': 30041, 'খ': 22981, 'র': 20806, 'ট': 19265, 'প': 16943, 'ন': 15478, 'ত': 13840}
    plt.bar(range(len(charFreq)), list(charFreq.values()), align='center')
    plt.xticks(range(len(charFreq)), list(charFreq.keys()), name="Nikosh")
    plt.show()
```

Where you should place a font family name instead of `Nikosh` in code above.

If you are getting `findfont: FontFamily not found` you can follow instructions in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26106170/1430690)