# Matplotlib cannot find fonts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use non-default fonts in matplotlib but keep on getting this warning/error.

```
findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
```

If I do

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Helvetica'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label='some label')
ax.legend()
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'some text', transform=ax.transAxes, size=25)

fig.savefig('text.png')
```

I get the error and both legend and text are in `Dejavu Sans`.

However, if I load `tex` by adding the extra line when setting up `rcParams`

```py
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

the warning still occurs if I have `ax.legend()` (but goes away if I don't have `ax.legend()`), although both the legend and the text are actually in Helvetica even if I get the warning.

Can someone tell me why this happens? And what should I do to use non-default fonts when not loading `tex`? I tried

```
sudo apt install msttcorefonts -qq
rm ~/.cache/matplotlib -rf
```

or uncomment the lines in `matplotlibrc` and rebuild but none of those worked.

Comment: The font cache might be affected - try deleting 'fontlist-v300.json' in your MPL installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue! Trying to install atlas typewriter. I partially used [matplotlib font not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085867/matplotlib-font-not-found)
although I did not have a cache to delete, instead there were two json files (fontlist-330.json). I manually added an entry to both jsons and it worked.

```
  {
      "fname": "/Users/XXUSERNAMEXX/Library/Fonts/AtlasTypewriter-Regular.ttf",
      "name": "Atlas Typewriter",
      "style": "normal",
      "variant": "normal",
      "weight": "normal",
      "stretch": "normal",
      "size": "scalable",
      "__class__": "FontEntry"
    },
```