# How to get XKCD font on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've managed to replicate the graphs in:

http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/showcase/xkcd.html

However my font does not look like that. How do I change the text font to the cool xkcd font?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679403/matplotlib-text-wont-display-in-xkcd-font

Comment: I have exactly copied the example from the link you provided. I had to upgrade my `matplotlib` version to `1.4.0`. This version includes `xkcd`. The plots resulting from the example are in `xkcd` style and work perfect.

Comment: It works for me as well. I asked about the FONT. :) I still get a regular font.

Comment: Please copy-paste into your question the precise program you are running and the resulting image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting xkcd plots using matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663986/getting-xkcd-plots-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from the output of `>>> help(plot.xkcd)`:

```
For best results, the "Humor Sans" font should be installed: it is
not included with matplotlib.
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
1. Downloaded the font Humor-Sans.ttf
2. Placed it in /usr/share/fonts/truetype/humor-sans
3. ran `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to refresh the font cache
and now it works.

Comment: And clear the matplotlib font cache after the installation: Win7: `%userprofile%\.matplotlib` Ubuntu: `~/.cache/matplotlib`