# How to get XKCD font working in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts, anaconda

[I've followed through this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812176/3130747).

I'm trying to reproduce the example [from here](http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/showcase/xkcd.html)

[This is how mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfJ1D.jpg)

[image]

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbaHg.jpg)

[image]

The code is on that page and at the end of this post

## System that I'm using

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

## Python version that I'm using

```
3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

## Matplotlib version

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
Out[37]: '1.5.1'
```

## Humorsans font installed on system

This shows that I have installed the font

```
$ fc-list | grep "Humo"
/usr/share/fonts/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf: Humor Sans:style=Regular
/home/vco/.fonts/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf: Humor Sans:style=Regular
```

## Matplotlib backend that I'm using

[Here is the back end that I'm using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663986/getting-xkcd-plots-using-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment29202942_19663986)

```
  plt.get_backend()
  Out[42]: 'TkAgg'
```

---

## Output error

I've followed the instructions from a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26148853/3130747);

Error from python output:

```
/home/vco/anaconda/envs/math_general/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1288:
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Humor Sans', 'Comic Sans MS'] not
found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans

  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

/home/vco/anaconda/envs/math_general/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1298:
  UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera
  Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=400:stretch=normal:size=medium.
  Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmtt10.ttf UserWarning)
```

I also tried to move the downloaded Humorsans font to

```
/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
```

But still got the following error

```
/home/vco/anaconda/envs/math_general/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1288: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Humor Sans', 'Comic Sans MS'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
/home/vco/anaconda/envs/math_general/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1298: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=400:stretch=normal:size=medium. Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmtt10.ttf
  UserWarning)
/home/vco/anaconda/envs/math_general/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1298: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=400:stretch=normal:size=large. Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmtt10.ttf
  UserWarning)
```

---

## code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.xkcd()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
ax.set_ylim([-30, 10])

data = np.ones(100)
data[70:] -= np.arange(30)

plt.annotate(
    'THE DAY I REALIZED\nI COULD COOK BACON\nWHENEVER I WANTED',
    xy=(70, 1), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'), xytext=(15, -10))

plt.plot(data)

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('my overall health')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.bar([-0.125, 1.0-0.125], [0, 100], 0.25)
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.set_xticks([0, 1])
ax.set_xlim([-0.5, 1.5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 110])
ax.set_xticklabels(['CONFIRMED BY\nEXPERIMENT', 'REFUTED BY\nEXPERIMENT'])
plt.yticks([])

plt.title("CLAIMS OF SUPERNATURAL POWERS")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663986/getting-xkcd-plots-using-matplotlib/22812176#22812176).

Comment: @lincolnfrias what, the one which is the first thing I reference in the post? I've looked ;)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I pointed to that because in my case, removing the matplolib cache in .config solved the problem.

Comment: @lincolnfrias "in my case..." < what is this referring to ? You've tested the code that I've posted on a similar setup or is this a different thing you're referring to? Cheers

Comment: Not the same setup and code, but also on Ubuntu (16.04).

Comment: @lincolnfrias so you have different setup, code, and a different version of Ubuntu. Can you let me know what I'm expected to do with the information you've given please?

Comment: In home directory I have a .config folder containing a matplotlib folder. There I removed the file fontList.cache. In other setups people have instead a separate .matplotlib folder (in the first level of their home, not inside the .config). This is detailed in the answer (and the commentaries to it) to the post I linked above.

Comment: @lincolnfrias please read my post, specifically the part "I've followed through this post" that links what you're referencing. If you have a working solution then please post it with code and system setup, otherwise these comments are useless.

Comment: Did you finally solve it?

Comment: @MartinThoma no I haven't solved this, maybe it'll be added to the millennium prize problems

Comment: @baxx, could there be another cache where matplotlib is looking apart from the ~/.config/matplotlib, ~/.cache/matplotlib or ~/.matplotlib?

Comment: @thoroc I'm not sure at the moment, I've not looked at this for a long time

Answer (score 7):

With `matplotlib==3.4.3` I had to do:

```
import shutil
import matplotlib

shutil.rmtree(matplotlib.get_cachedir())
```

Comment: This worked for me (Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.04, matplotlib 3.6.2). I had to restart the notebook kernel (and remember to remove the lines that deleted the cache so they don't run again) for it to take effect.

Answer (score 6):

Try deleting Matplotlib cache and see if it works (i.e., `rm -r ~/.cache/matplotlib`).

In my case it solved the problem:

```
user@host:~$ ./xkcd.py
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1241:
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['xkcd', 'Humor Sans', 'Comic Sans MS'] not found.
Falling back to DejaVu Sans. (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
user@host:~$ rm -r ~/.cache/matplotlib
user@host:~$ ./xkcd.py
user@host:~$
```

Comment: This worked for me (Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.04, matplotlib 3.6.2). I had to restart the notebook kernel for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you still see an error after installing HumorSans font, I advise running:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
```

It will rebuild the font cache.

Comment: This gives an error in matplotlib 3.6.2

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I get: "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.font_manager' has no attribute '_rebuild'"

Comment: Possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647041/3275464)