# matplotlib does not detect font

Tags: matplotlib, archlinux

When i use `fontname=` with the `Humor Sans` font I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1288: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Humor Sans', 'Comic Sans MS'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I have the `Humor Sans` installed.  I use archlinux and I installed the [ttf-humor-sans](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-humor-sans/) package.

I have ensured that the font config cache `fc-list` finds the `Humor Sans` font:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i Humor
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf: Humor Sans:style=Regular
```

Comment: Does `fc-list | grep -i humor` give you any output?  And if you run `fc-cache -s` (rebuild the font cache) and check again?

Comment: It gives me: `$ fc-list | grep -i`: `humor/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf: Humor Sans:style=Regular`. After `fc-cache -s` the problem persists

Comment: I solved it with rm .cache/matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache. For some, it would be in ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache

Comment: @lincolnfrias You are wright. This is the solution

Comment: Now I have a collateral problem: accents don't displayed correctly: "DISTÀNCIA" showed as "DIST?NCIA". Is there any utf issues with this font?

Comment: I have the same problem. I did not find any solution to it.

Comment: @lincolnfrias I asked for [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816904/matplotlib-humor-sans-does-not-displayed-correctly-accents)

Answer (score 3):

Well, after properly looking at it, it is a kind of a bug.  Using the following test:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font_cache = [i for i in
    fm.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
    if 'umor' in i]
for i in font_cache:
    print(i)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1],[1],'o')
ax.set_title('My Title', fontname='Humor Sans')
#ax.set_title('My Title', fontname='Homemade Apple')
fig.savefig('tmp.png')
```

I have compared the behaviour of the `Humor Sans` against `Homemade Apple` (a free google font that i package into an AUR package).  And the issue is that `matplotlib` does **matching** on the font names specified in `fontname=`, the matching does not use only the name but several properties of the font.  in `/home/grochmal/mat3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py` you see the matching:

```
for font in fontlist:
    if (directory is not None and
        os.path.commonprefix([font.fname, directory]) != directory):
        continue
    # Matching family should have highest priority, so it is multiplied
    # by 10.0
    score = \
        self.score_family(prop.get_family(), font.name) * 10.0 + \
        self.score_style(prop.get_style(), font.style) + \
        self.score_variant(prop.get_variant(), font.variant) + \
        self.score_weight(prop.get_weight(), font.weight) + \
        self.score_stretch(prop.get_stretch(), font.stretch) + \
        self.score_size(prop.get_size(), font.size)
    if score < best_score:
         best_score = score
         best_font = font
    if score == 0:
         break
```

Unfortunately `Humor Sans` never reaches the matching phase because not all `prop.get_...` can be filled in.  In essence it never gets included into `fontlist`.  `Homemade Apple` is included because it can fill all the properties.

The difference in font properties can be seen as follows:

```
[me@haps aur]# otfinfo --info /usr/share/fonts/TTF/HomemadeApple.ttf
Family:              Homemade Apple
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Homemade Apple
PostScript name:     HomemadeApple
Preferred family:    Homemade Apple
Preferred subfamily: Regular
Mac font menu name:  Homemade Apple
Version:             Version 1.000
Unique ID:           FontDiner,Inc: Homemade Apple: 2010
Description:         Copyright (c) 2010 by Font Diner, Inc. All rights reserved.
Designer:            Font Diner, Inc
Designer URL:        http://www.fontdiner.com
Manufacturer:        Font Diner, Inc
Vendor URL:          http://www.fontdiner.com
Trademark:           Homemade Apple is a trademark of Font Diner, Inc.
Copyright:           Copyright (c) 2010 by Font Diner, Inc. All rights reserved.
License URL:         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
License Description: Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
Vendor ID:           DINR

[me@haps aur]# otfinfo --info /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Humor-Sans-1.0.ttf
Family:              Humor Sans
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Humor Sans
PostScript name:     HumorSans
Version:             Version 2.9 28/3/09
Unique ID:           Fontifier 2.9 (172) www.fontifier.com Humor Sans
Copyright:           Copyright (c) Randall Munroe's biggest fan 2009. Created by www.fontifier.com. usa-1lip-4fvu15
Vendor ID:           Alts
```

There missing fields from `Humor Sans` are not required, to be fair there are several inconsistencies in how fonts are described inside TTF (google *italic* vs. *oblique* for an example) therefore it isn't `Humor Sans` fault either.  Your issue is a combination of inconsistencies in a file format with a lack of standardised code to deal with them.

I would suggest to find a different font that looks similar enough.  Either editing the TTF or the matplotlib code is very tricky and might result in other problems.

Comment: So, should we file a bug against humor sans package or against matplotlib package? Thanks for all your corrections and code.

Comment: I'd argue that both.  Both are at fault to some extent: `matplotlib` for assuming too much from fonts and `Humor Sans` for not trying to be compatible as much as it can.  Yet, i believe, this is the kind of bug that will not get fixed.  Editing the matching code in `matplotlib` is too error prone, and font packages (`Humor Sans`) are often unmaintained (e.g. i package `Homemade Apple` but is do not own the font files, if that font presented such error i would be powerless).

Comment: So what will we do for fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

Humor Sans from the AUR works for me.  However, I had to delete the font-cache first: 
`rm ~/.cache/matplotlib/fontlist-v330.json`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812176